# A problem about sets

Tags: set-theory

Given set $X$, does there exist sets A and B that are subsets of $X \times X $ (Descartes product) and satisfy the following condition:

$A \cup B = X \times X$

for every a $\in X$, $(\{a\} \times X) \cap$ A is finite, for every $b \in X$, $(X \times \{b\}) \cap B$ is finite.

Consider $X$ as finite set, the problem is trivial.

Consider $X$ as countable set, the answer is "yes". we can arrange the elements in $X$ as a sequence {$x_n$}，and we take $A =\{(x_i,x_j), i \leq j\}$, $B = \{(x_i,x_j), j \leq i\}$.

Does this hold for arbitrary sets?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "limited"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean "finite".

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: For an arbitrary set X, does it exist sets A and B of this kind?  I can only solve when X is finite or countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not true for uncountable sets, here is a proof by contradiction.

Let $X$ be an uncountable set. Let $a_n$ be a countably infinite sequence of points in $X$. For each $a_i$, the set of points of the form ($a_i$,$x$) is finite in $A$. So for each $a_i$ there are uncountably many points of the form ($a_i$,$x$) in $B$.
Now as there are finitely many points $x_j$ in $X$ for which ($a_i$,$x_j$) belongs to $A$ for each $a_i$, and $X$ is uncountable, hence there will be some point $y \in X$ such that ($a_i$,$y$) does not belong to $A$ for any $a_i$. So ($a_i$,$y$) belongs to $B$ for all $a_i$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for $X = \omega_1$. For all $n \in \omega$ let $s_n$ be the maximum $s$ such that $(n,s) \in A$. This is a countable set, so it can't be cofinal in $\omega_1$. So there is some $s'$ bigger than all of them. So for all $n \in \omega$, $(n,s') \in B$.